# php pow function not work with laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently creating the application to calculate monthly payment for loan. In the controller function, I have to php pow function for my calculation.But this calculation does not give the correct answer. It only saves 0.0 in the database.

This is my controller function code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $company_details = new Company();

        $company_details->company_name = $request->company_name;
        $company_details->loan_amount = $request->loan_amount;
        $company_details->interest_rate = $request->interest_rate;
        $company_details->maximum_time_period = $request->maximum_time_period;

        $company_details->monthly_rental =$request->loanAmount*($request->interest_rate/12) / (1- pow(1+$request->interest_rate, -$request->maximum_time_period));

        $company_details->save();

        return view('addLoandetails');
    }
```

This is my migration file code

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->integer('loan_amount');
            $table->float('interest_rate');
            $table->integer('maximum_time_period');
            $table->float('monthly_rental');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: it only saves 0.0 in the database not perform the calculation

Comment: try debug. Just check what you getting in your $request->interest_rate and $request->maximum_time_period variables.

Comment: Is it possbile to show the value of $request->interest_rate and $request->maximum_time_period.

Comment: if i do this kinf of simple calculation it saves correct answer. $company_details->monthly_rental = $request->loan_amount * $request->interest_rate/12;

Comment: `-$request->maximu...` there is a minus, is it correct?

Comment: Ankur Tiwari yes those $request->interest_rate and $request->maximum_time_period correctly save to the database

Comment: try using `-1*-$request->maximum_time_period` instead of `-$request->maximum_time_period`

Comment: yes shobi we have to use that  minus(-) sign.

Comment: Can you show some value that is saved in your database? Not monthly_rental but the other values

Comment: LB  100000  4.00  2  0.00  / LOLC  100000  2.00  24  0.00

Comment: _Side note:_ [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) is a native PHP-function and doesn't have anything to do with the framework your using. Laravel (or any other framework) can't change the behavior of native PHP functions.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson  how can i perform this kind of calculation

Comment: As per the above comment if pow() now working with the framework. You can create your own function for the same in laravel

Comment: @AnkurTiwari - The function _does_ work _regardless_ of the framework. No need to write your own implementation. The OP simply needs to do some debugging, like checking the values being passed to the function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay Thanks, I understand that why we are trying to debug and thanks for your clarification on pow with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

When $base is negative and $exponent is a negative odd number:

```
<?php 

 echo(pow(-3, -3)); 

?>
```

output will be: 0.037037037037037

So check what value you are passing in the base and exponent.

Reference: [See the pow function results here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-pow-function/)